# Does JsonProperty in Json.Net causes performance overhead

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Consider there is a class like

```
public class Test{
     [JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name {get; set;}
     [JsonProperty("age")]
     public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

I want this to be serialized like this:  `{"name": "a", "age": "10"}`
There is a setting  `CamelCaseNamingStrategy`  in Json.net library. If I dont use the  `JsonProperty`  I can still achieve the above result. 
The example given above is a small, but what if we have to serialize/deserialize bigger models frequently. Will adding the JsonProperty attribute for each property be a good thing for performance?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/.

Comment: After you're done, if you want my *guess*, it's that any performance overhead of adding some extra attributes vs using a naming strategy is de minimis compared to the benefits code clarity, readability, and simplicity.  Structure your code in the simplest possible way, then profile it if a problem arises.  I highly doubt the presence of absence of attributes will make a difference since [contract information is cached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182).

Comment: And for simplicity I prefer using a contract resolver, then a [type-level naming strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805815/3744182), and then lastly individual `[JsonProperty]` attributes.  But sometimes your framework doesn't give you easy access to the contract resolver so using attributes is simpler.

Comment: Most serialization tools have very good strategy cache implementations for dealing with things like this; I wouldn't *expect* it to make much difference, but: measure it! The only meaningful test is one that matches your scenario and data.